# Is the mourning for a late relative dependent on the state of their relationship before death?

Tags: halacha, death, family-members, mourning-aveilus

Are the *halochos* (laws) about observing mourning rituals for a relative (e.g., [shiva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_(Judaism)), shloshim, [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bereavement_in_Judaism#Stages_of_mourning)), affected in any way by the state of the relationship between the mourner and deceased before his death?

A particular case might be if the two had been estranged for many years before the death.

(Note: If such a situation affects you in real life, do not rely on any advice you read online. Instead, [contact an Orthodox rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) directly.)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: I have seen people visit the grave of someone that they had a dispute with to daven for them and for resolution of the dispute. **Even if you are in the right** it is better to end the dispute before it is no longer possible. Consider that a kohen is **required** to be metameh for the seven immediate relatives. For those who are not yet in this situation **please** speak to a rav who can help.

Comment: If he is he alive, no. You are not supposed to sit shiva for someone who is alive. Otherwise, yes.

Comment: ...although you should of course consult a knowledgeable rabbi regarding the specifics of your case, since certain details could affect the law.

Comment: Hey there, Mike, welcome to Mi Yodeya :) ....you might want to think about consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: I had heard that some had said that one is not required to sit shiva for a father who had a majorly nasty break-up with his son; though of course you should consult a rabbi you trust for specific guidance for your situation. I'm sorry to hear that it's come to this.